# ImageView does not adopt to the size of the Relativelayout -> wrap_content

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

I am trying to get a layout like this:

[my layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jTtPe.png)

the red colour beckground is just for better visualisation.

and i want that if the text in the edittext exeeds the given space of the edittext, that it expands only below and wraps the text. The Relativelayout and the constraintlayout including the edittext do the behavior i need but the imageview for the background won't expand to the now larger content of edittext.

[problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eE1UW.png)

I tried this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/red">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="6dp"
        android:minHeight="60dp"
        android:maxHeight="300dp"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">


        <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/layout2"
            android:layout_width="315dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true">


            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText"
                android:layout_width="315dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerInParent="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
                android:maxHeight="290dp"
                android:text="@string/test"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textAllCaps="false"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                app:layout_constrainedHeight="true"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/layout2"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


        </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/background"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:alpha="0.4"
            android:background="@drawable/add_skill_design"
            android:maxHeight="300dp"
            android:minHeight="60dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/add_skill_upload_circle"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:src="@drawable/circle_skill"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/add_skill_upload_remove"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/remove"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            />

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

What am i doing wrong? I need this for a project.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the vertical alignment of the `ImageView` with the background drawable to  depend on the boundaries of the `ConstraintLayout`:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/background"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:alpha="0.4"
        android:background="@drawable/add_skill_design"
        android:maxHeight="300dp"
        android:minHeight="60dp"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/layout2"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/layout2" />
```

[image]

Comment: jesus christ you are my hero, thanks a lot!!

Comment: I am doing a project (university) and i am breaking my head since 2 days over this problem which i could not solve. Thank you again, you will not believe how much helps me